# Given a cumulative distribution function, show that this is also a CDF

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-distributions

Let $F$ be a cumulative distribution function. Show that $$G\left( x \right) = F\left( {\sqrt {x - 1} } \right) - F\left( { - \sqrt {x - 1}  - } \right)$$ for $x \geqslant 1$ and $0$ otherwise, is also a CDF. $f\left( {x - } \right) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{y \to x - } f\left( y \right)$ denotes a left-side limit.

My solution: We have to show that $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  + \infty } G\left( x \right) = 1$, $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  - \infty } G\left( x \right) = 0$, $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to a + } G\left( x \right) = G\left( a \right)$ and that $G$ is non-decreasing.

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to a + } G\left( x \right) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to a + } \left( {F\left( {\sqrt {x - 1} } \right) - F\left( { - \sqrt {x - 1}  - } \right)} \right) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to a + } F\left( {\sqrt {x - 1} } \right) - \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to a + } F\left( { - \sqrt {x - 1}  - } \right) = F\left( {\sqrt {a - 1} } \right) - \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to a + } \mathop {\lim }\limits_{y \to x - } F\left( { - \sqrt {y - 1} } \right)$$

How do I show that $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to a + } \mathop {\lim }\limits_{y \to x - } F\left( { - \sqrt {y - 1} } \right) = F\left( { - \sqrt {a - 1}  - } \right)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** (on alternative route):

Let it be that $F$ is the CDF of random variable $X$. Now find the CDF of random variable $X^2+1$.

Comment: That's a smart way to go about it. Much less work, too. Very nice

Answer (score 1):

You need to show that $$
  \lim_{x\to a+} F(-\sqrt{x-1}-) = F(-\sqrt{a-1}-).
$$
Let $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converge to $a$ from the right, i.e. $x_n > a$ for all $n \in\mathbb{N}$ and $x_n \to a$ for $n \to \infty$. Then $z_n = -\sqrt{x_n-1}$ converges to $z = -\sqrt{a-1}$ from the left. Now, since $F$ is right-continuous, the function $u \mapsto F(u-)$ is left-continuous ($\star$), and therefore $\lim_{n\to\infty} F(z_n-) = F(z-)$. Which immediately yields $$
  \lim_{x\to a+} F(-\sqrt{x-1}-) = \lim_{n\to\infty} F(z_n-) = F(z-) = F(-\sqrt{a-1}-).
$$

($\star$) uses that $F$ increases monotonically and is bounded, which ensures that the left-sided limits exist. For a formal proof, you probably need to swap two limits.

---

**This was the answers to the original question about how to show that** $$
  \lim_{x \to a+} \lim_{y\to x-} F(-\sqrt{y-1}) = F(-\sqrt{a-1}-),
$$
**which is irrelevant because the original question wrongly assumed that** $$
  F(-\sqrt{x-1}-) = \lim_{y\to x-} F(-\sqrt{y-1}).
$$

For $y \in [1,\infty)$, the function $\sqrt{y-1}$ is continuous and increases monotonically. Now assume $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to $x$ from the left, i.e. if $y_n < x$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $y_n \to x$ for $n \to \infty$. Then, because of the stated monotonicity and continuity, $\sqrt{y_n-1}$ converges to $\sqrt{x-1}$ also from the left, and $-\sqrt{y_n-1}$ thus converges to $-\sqrt{x-1}$ from the right. Therefore, $$
  \lim_{y\to x-} F(-\sqrt{y-1}) = F(-\sqrt{x-1}).
$$

That leaves us with $$
  \lim_{x \to a+} F(-\sqrt{x-1}).
$$
Assume $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to $a$ from the right, i.e. $x_n > a$ for all $n$ and $x_n \to a$ for $n \to \infty$. Using the monotonicity and continuity of $\sqrt{x-1}$ again yields that $-\sqrt{x_n-1}$ converges to $-\sqrt{a-1}$ from the left (the "-"-sign again causes the "direction" of convergence to change), which yields $$
  \lim_{x \to a+} F(-\sqrt{x-1}) = F(-\sqrt{a-1}-).
$$

Comment: @Alen Where am I supposed to have assumed that?

Comment: Nowhere, my mistake. Good answer

Comment: Hm, but I think the derivation in your question contains a mistake. You presume that $F(-\sqrt{x-1}-) = \lim_{y\to x-} F(-\sqrt{y-1})$. But the actual limit you should be using is $\lim_{z\to -\sqrt{x-1}-} F(z)$ which (because the "-"-sign again changes the direction) equals $\lim_{y\to x+} F(-\sqrt{y-1})$.

Comment: Ah, yes, you are right, that prevented me to arrive at the same conclusion you did

Comment: Hm, my answers starts from the wrongly posed question in your answer, so while I think it's technically correct, it doesn't actually help with your problem.

Comment: It does, $F$ is non-decreasing by assumption, so every argument you've applied still holds for what I need to show

Comment: @Alan See my edit. I believe the essential insight is that if $F$ is right-continuous, $u \to F(u-)$ is left-continuous.